# get value of selected checkbox from different questions

Tags: jquery

I am making a online test website in which there are multiple questions . I have check box for selecting the answers . There are more then one question . The problem is how to get the values of the selected checkbox for each question's answers and send them in a form such as

suppose there are four options in first question (a,b,c,d) and question id is 2 . then when a user selects the option b,c then the data should be get via jquery and stored in a variable . I have used each for this . my code is

```
            var chkArray = [];
            var chkQues = [];
            var answer;
            $(".answer_chk_box:checked").each(function() {
                chkArray.push($.trim($(this).val()));
                chkQues.push($.trim($(this).attr("qid")));
                //alert(chkQues);
            });
            answer = chkArray.join(',');
            Question_id=chkQues
```

this works fine if there is only one question . the value for `answer is "b,c"` and question_id is `2` . But when there are multiple questions . everything gets messed up . How can we get values for multiple questions separate such that for one question's answer we can send one ajax call properly .

Comment: this is not the answer, but related, do you know about `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()` ? I'm sure it would help a lot

Comment: combine comment above with the fish_ball's answer, if you are able to play with class names. If not, you can alter your sample in the way I've given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say you simply create an object to describe a Question and Answer pair.

http://jsfiddle.net/zGQH5/2/

```
function getQandAs(){
  //Object array to store all of our data
  var questionsAndAnswers = [];
  $(".answer_chk_box:checked").each(function() {
      //This object represents a question ID and all of its selected answers
      var questionAnswer = new Object();
      questionAnswer.answer = $.trim($(this).val());
      questionAnswer.questionId = $.trim($(this).attr("qid"));
      questionsAndAnswers.push(questionAnswer);
  });

  //these lines just demo it working
  $(questionsAndAnswers).each(function(index){
      alert(questionsAndAnswers[index].answer + " & " + questionsAndAnswers[index].questionId);
  });
}
```

Comment: `  $(questionsAndAnswers).each(function(index){
    chkArray.push(questionsAndAnswers[index].answer + " & " + questionsAndAnswers[index].questionId);
  });` i modified it a bit so that i can send all values in on ajax call . WOHOOO . You saved my life . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

just use `name="field[]"` on the checkbox field:

```
<form id="questions">

  <article id="question-1">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="question-1-choice[]" value="A" />
      Choice A
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="question-1-choice[]" value="B" />
      Choice B
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="question-1-choice[]" value="C" />
      Choice C
    </label>
  </article>

  <article id="question-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="question-2-choice[]" value="A" />
      Choice A
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="question-2-choice[]" value="B" />
      Choice B
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="question-2-choice[]" value="C" />
      Choice C
    </label>
  </article>

</form>
```

Comment: i am also using a custom attribute here `<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="answer_chk_box" qid="6" value="a">` `qid` for passing the question id

Comment: In this way, you can get the natural structure of the form fields in the server-side, no need to preprocess before submit.

Comment: thank you for your solution but there are not only multiple types of questions but also multiple types . I wanted to use jquery . Is it not possible ?

Comment: for different question type, you can just assign appropriate input tag types for them, but on the server side, you got a key-value(s) pair anyway. If you consist to use jquery to process them, I suggest you to use the jquery.form.js plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/form/

Answer (score 1):

create 2D array of options including questions id rand answer id.

```
var chkArray = [][];
 $(".answer_chk_box:checked").each(function() {
                chkArray.push($.trim($(this).attr("qid")), $.trim($(this).val()));

            });
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Answer (score 1):

First of all using custom attributes is not recommended. It is better to use data attributes. So you have inputs like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="something" data-qid="1" class="answer_chk_box" />
```

You should collect all the answers into hash:

```
var answers = {};
$(".answer_chk_box:checked").each(function() {
    var qid = $(this).data('qid');
    var answer = $.trim($(this).val());
    if(!answers[qid]){
        answers[qid] = [];
    }

    if(answers[qid].indexOf(answer) === -1){
        answers[qid][] = answer;
    }
});

//console.log(answers);
```

Comment: its perfect for the first question then again for the second question it returns one value at a time for eg when i alert this what i get 1st alert `a,b` 2nd alert `a,b,a` 3rd alert `a,b,a,b` it should be 1st alert `a,b` and 2nd alert `a,b`

Comment: ok then I have changed the code a bit. Now each key of the hash is array and before adding an answer you should check if it's not in the array yet